# State not updating in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

following is the code that i used in order to manage the state but unfortunately my state is not updating when using redux
the action is as given below:

```
export let incNumber = ()=>{
    return {
        type: 'INCREMENT'

    }
}
export let decNumber = ()=>{
    return {
        type: 'DECREMENT'
        
    }
}
```

while the reducer is as given below:

```
import mainReducer from "./reducers";
import { createStore } from "redux";
const store = createStore(mainReducer, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
export default store;
```

the main app.js file is as given below:

```
import './App.css';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {incNumber, decNumber} from './actions/index';
function App() {
  let myState = useSelector((state)=> {
    return state.changeTheNumber;
  });
  console.log(myState);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <>
      <div className="main-div">
      

      <div className="container">
  
      <h1>Increment/Decrement counter</h1>
      <h4>using React and Redux</h4>
      
      <div className="quantity">
        <a className="quantity__minus" title="Decrement" onClick={()=>dispatch(decNumber())}><span>-</span></a>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" className="quantity__input" defaultValue={myState}/>
        <h1>{myState}</h1>
        <a className="quantity__plus" title="Increment" onClick={()=>dispatch(incNumber())}><span>+</span></a>
      </div>
  
          </div>
        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the code of mainReducer is:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import changeTheNumber from "./upDown";
const mainReducer = combineReducers({
    changeTheNumber
})
export default mainReducer;
```

updown reducer is given as:

```
const initialState = 0;

const changeTheNumber = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "INCREMENT": return state + 1;
        case "DECREMENT": return state - 1;
        default: return state;
    }
}

export default changeTheNumber;
```

now the problem is that although as soon as i click on + button, the updated value is being shown on console in the browser but is not updated in the field specified. Any solutions?

Comment: [Writing in All Caps Is Like Shouting](https://www.lifewire.com/why-not-to-write-in-all-caps-1173242)

Comment: The problem is likely in `mainReducer` which you don't show us. You probably do something like `changeTheNumber++` which mutates your state, rather than returning a new copy of the state.

Comment: bro following is the code of mainReducer:
```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import changeTheNumber from "./upDown";
const mainReducer = combineReducers({
    changeTheNumber
})
export default mainReducer;
```

Comment: can you show upDown reducer?

Comment: see in the code now bro

Comment: The issue is that you're using `defaultValue` instead of `value`. `defaultValue` only sets the initial value of the input.